# Swift wait for requestAVAsset to complete before adding to array

Tags: arrays, swift, phasset, phimagemanager

func getAlbumAssets(albumName: String) async -> Array {

```
var albumAssets: [AlbumAsset] = [AlbumAsset]()
var albumAssetsResult = PHFetchResult<AnyObject>()

let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
fetchOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "title = %@", albumName)

let albumCollection:PHFetchResult = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with: .album, subtype: .any, options: fetchOptions)
if albumCollection.firstObject != nil {
    
    albumAssetsResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(in: albumCollection.firstObject!, options: nil) as! PHFetchResult<AnyObject>
    
    let requestImageOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
    requestImageOptions.version = .current
    requestImageOptions.resizeMode = .exact
    requestImageOptions.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat
    requestImageOptions.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true
    requestImageOptions.isSynchronous = true
    requestImageOptions.progressHandler = {(progress, error, stop, info) in
        if(progress == 1.0) {
            print("Downloaded Shared Image from iCloud")
        }else{
            print("\(progress)")
        }
    }
    
    let requestVideoOptions = PHVideoRequestOptions()
    requestVideoOptions.version = .current
    requestVideoOptions.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat
    requestVideoOptions.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true
    requestVideoOptions.progressHandler = {(progress, error, stop, info) in
        if(progress == 1.0) {
            print("Downloaded Shared Video from iCloud")
        }else{
            print("\(progress)")
        }
    }
    
    lazy var imageManager = {
        return PHImageManager() // PHCachingImageManager() //
    }()
    
    let asset = albumAssetsResult.object(at: 1) as! PHAsset
    
    let imageSize = CGSize(width: asset.pixelWidth/2, height: asset.pixelHeight/2)
    
    var converted = asset.mediaType == .image ? Image("iva") : Image("vai")
    
    let index = 0
    let album = albumName
    let name = asset.localIdentifier
    let cdate = asset.creationDate!
    var mediaasset = ""
    var mediaduration = CMTimeGetSeconds(.zero)
    let imageType = asset.mediaType
    let imageWidth = CGFloat(asset.pixelWidth)
    let imageHeight = CGFloat(asset.pixelHeight)
    let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0.0, longitude: 0.0)
    if (asset.location?.coordinate.latitude != nil){
        _ = asset.location!.coordinate
    }
    let cover = false
    
    if asset.mediaType == .image {
        imageManager.requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: imageSize, contentMode: .aspectFill, options: requestImageOptions, resultHandler: { (image, info) -> Void in
            if image != nil {
                converted = Image(uiImage: image!)
            }
        })
    } else if imageType == .video {
        imageManager.requestAVAsset(forVideo: asset, options: requestVideoOptions, resultHandler: {(asset1, audioMix, info) -> Void in
            let avaURLasset = asset1 as! AVURLAsset
            mediaasset = avaURLasset.url.absoluteString
            mediaduration = CMTimeGetSeconds(avaURLasset.duration)
        })
    }
    
    let newAsset = AlbumAsset(index: index, album: album, name: name, createDate: cdate, asset: mediaasset, duration: mediaduration, image: converted, imageType: imageType, imageWidth: imageWidth, imageHeight: imageHeight, location: location, cover: cover)
    albumAssets.append(newAsset)
    
}
return albumAssets
```

}

.requestImage for .image works great and returns only the first image in the album requested. However the .requestAVAsset takes a bit longer and returns nothing.  I see that the return albumAssets array runs before the video is even loaded.

How can I make it so that the video finishes loading and then continues to add to the array albumAssets.

New to Swift and did try DispatchGroup() but found that the Group.wait() is deprecated.

Comment: One thought that comes to mind is that your `albumAssets.append(newAsset)` should happen within the completion handler / block of `imageManager.requestAVAsset`

Comment: Thanks for responding. When I had it in the .requestAVAsset the return albumAssets finished first that was outside the .requestAVAsset. I receive error placing return in the completion handler of .requestAVAsset.

Comment: Yes that makes sense. Ideally you can't return till this completion block finishes which is when your video is loaded. You kind of need to `await` for the `requestAVAsset` to finish before proceeding. There are several ways to do that. One could be using a completion handler yourself rather than returning the array or another idea discussed here on how to await requests when working with `PHImageManager` https://gist.github.com/sindresorhus/b37c9ab01b79b754ca1690aaa266c410